# Objective C - How to Create a Scrollable tab bar with multiple tabs in iOS

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uitabbarcontroller

1. **In programmatically, I created dynamic tabs to below code.**

NSMutableArray *dataArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

```
  UIStoryboard *storyboard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
            bundle:nil];
  BasicIn *viewController1=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BasicInfo"];
  viewController1.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"contactTab.png"];
  viewController1.tabBarItem.title=@"Basic Info";
  [dataArray addObject: viewController1];

  UIStoryboard *storyboard1=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
            bundle:nil];
  AddImageVC *viewController2=[storyboard1 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddImageVC"];
  viewController2.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"planTab.png"];
  viewController2.tabBarItem.title=@"Images";
  [dataArray addObject:viewController2];

   UITabBarController  *myTabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
   self.myTabBarController.viewControllers =dataArray;
   [self.view addSubview:[self.myTabBarController view]];

    UIColor *appTintColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:19.0/255 green:89.0/255 blue:234.0/255 alpha:1.0];

    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont
                                                                                   fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:10.0f],
                                                            NSForegroundColorAttributeName : appTintColor
                                                            }forState:UIControlStateSelected];        


Now It`s created a normal tab bar function.you can create dynamic tabs in tab bar controller with this code, without using any 3 party framework.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the `UITabBarController` cannot do scrollable tab bars. It can only handle 1-5 bar buttons, after that you will get a *more* button as last element to access the other buttons.

The documentation says:

> If you add six or more custom view controllers to a tab bar
>   controller, the tab bar controller displays only the first four items
>   plus the standard More item on the tab bar.

[Read more about UITabBarController here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller)

That said, you can always add your own custom UI components to do the job. It might not be so difficult, depending on your exact requirements.